# AutoMapper Mapping Depth

Tags: automapper

Is there any way to set the "depth" of mapping on one entity while mapping to dto?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a recursive structure?

Answer (score 1):

Not yet. There is a discussion going on about this here https://github.com/jbogard/AutoMapper/pull/21

Answer (score 1):

It is now possible to set the depth with the Automapper 2.0.

You can find it here: http://automapper.org/blog/2011/09/22/automapper-20-released/